# Skip need to specify ECS URI for docker images

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

Right now I do this:

```
docker run -it --rm 201811111111.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/foo/bar:latest /bin/sh
```

Is there a way to configure Docker so I can just do this?

```
docker run -it --rm foo/bar:latest /bin/sh
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no global configuration you can set to make this happen. However, for each tag, you can do this:

```
docker tag 201811111111.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/foo/bar:latest foo/bar:latest
```

which lets you do this:

```
docker run -it --rm foo/bar:latest /bin/sh
```

`docker images` will show both the images.

Comment: That's pretty neat. I would need to do this for each `foo/bar`, tho?

Comment: @Narfanator Upvote and accept my answer if you think it is useful so that others know this is the right answer, thanks! Yes, you need to tag each image if you want to run it as `foo/bar` for example.